# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\folder\phpfile.php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am very new to PHP and I am learning about PHP PDO class but the moment when I just create the new instance of PDO class with three parameters ($dsn, $user, $password)) and run localhost this error comes out and i tried a a lot even searched but couldn't be able to resolve this.I attach the code for reference. Please, anybody, know what's the problem let me know. Thanks

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'pdoposts';

//Set DSN

$dsn = 'mysql:host='. $host .';dbname='.$dbname;

//Creat a PDO instance

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
```

Comment: are you able to connect to MySQL with any other client without a password?

Comment: Is "no password" the same as an empty password? I literally don't know/remember. Could you try `$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user);`?

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys my problem was solved. Actually, it was a port issue I was using port 3307 and I changed it to 3306 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case database port was the main issue i found. When I changed port to  3307 (in your case it might be other.)

Below was the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\phppdo\index.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\phppdo\index.php(8): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\phppdo\index.php on line 8**

Here is the working code:

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$port = 3307;
$password = "";
$db = "phppdo";
$dbcon = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;port=$port;dbname=$db", $user, $password);
```

[image]here you can find the current server name (please find the screenshot attached.)

Comment: FYI, 3307 is a database *port*, not host, and it must be set the other way

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions:

1. Make sure there are no other MySQL servers running if there are uninstall them, then install XAMPP again the problem might be the settings you have made yourself.
2. Change your host from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1";
3. You didn't specify the port which is usually port 3306 on windows.
4. Finally make sure there are no empty spaces in your empty password.
5. It should look like this including code to catch errors

setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

?>